# Counting indexes though positions and the amount of positions and incorrect positions

Tags: python, position

I am trying to make a master mind python game, but at the moment I can't think of an efficient idea for checking the correct and incorrect position, I've asked multiple questions about it and people just keep telling me to optimize it and make it not look messy, when I'm just sending the entire program with no context, so ill just send the idea and how I want to accomplish this. I'll tell you that I have the length and the randomized number down, I just need to measure the correct and incorrect position

```
answer = 201234#---------------------->201234
#                                      ------
                             #position|012345
#                                      ------
line = 202314#------------------------>202314
```

if done correctly, the answer to this should be 3 correct positions, and 3 incorrect positions. however, accomplishing this with an random length choice of both answer and line is tough.

my first attempt was hard coding it with just copied and pasted check if statements, it was rudimentary and it wouldn't work for any length above 3 characters unless i copy and pasted more.

second attempt was to do the copy and pasting for functions, and to use arguments in the functions to tell me which number, line and length of the number i was using

third attempt was a for loop for the checks, but the issue with that is that it would just count it as a point regardless of the position, so i ruled that out immediately.

if you dont know how master mind is programmed, in the example code above, if the position for answer and line were the same number, then it would add 1 to the correct positions, easy enough for that.
but with the incorrect positions, it takes a number from answer that doesn't have a same corresponding number in line, then it would take that number and see if there were any **1** same number ***(pairs)*** were in the incorrect position in line, then if so it would add 1 to the incorrect position.
the problem with what ive done previously is that no matter what it will take the number and if there were 2 numbers of the wrong position on line, then it would add two instead of taking pairs and leaving the other one alone

as long as i have an answer to this issue then i can take that and insert it into my current master mind game.

long story short i want the final code to be optimized, and come up with 3 correct positions and 3 incorrect positions, and I want the check to be versatile in length.

If you want the brute forced version for reference, here it is:

```
def brute_force_checking(line,linelength):
    global board
    superguess = line
    superanswer = answer
    if answer[0] == superguess [0]:
        right_spot += 1
        superanswer[0] = "x"
        superguess[0] = "y"
    elif superanswer[0] == superguess[1]:
        wrong_spot +=1
        superguess[1] = "w"
    elif superanswer[0] == superguess[2]:
        wrong_spot +=1
        superguess[2] = "w"
    if len(line) > 3:
        if superanswer[0] == superguess[3]:
            wrong_spot += 1
            superguess[3] = "w"
        if len(line) > 4:
            if superanswer[0] == superguess[4]:
                wrong_spot +=1
                superguess[4] ="w"

    if superanswer[1] == superguess [1]:
        right_spot += 1
        superanswer[1] = "x"
        superguess[1] = "y"
    elif superanswer[1] == superguess[0]:
        wrong_spot +=1
        superguess[0] ="w"
    elif superanswer[1] == superguess[2]:
        wrong_spot +=1
        superguess[2] ="w"
    if len(line) > 3:
        if superanswer[1] == superguess[3]:
            wrong_spot +=1
            superguess[3] ="w"
        if len(line) > 4:
            if superanswer[1] == superguess[4]:
                wrong_spot +=1
                superguess[4] ="w"

    if superanswer[2] == superguess [2]:
        right_spot += 1
        superanswer[2] = "x"
        superguess[2] = "y"
    elif superanswer[2] == superguess[1]:
        wrong_spot +=1
        superguess[1] ="w"
    elif superanswer[2] == superguess[0]:
        wrong_spot +=1
        superguess[0] ="w"
    if len(line) > 3:
        if superanswer[2] == superguess[3]:
            wrong_spot +=1
            superguess[3] ="w"
        if len(line) > 4:
            if superanswer[2] == superguess[4]:
                wrong_spot +=1
                superguess[4] ="w"
    if len(line) > 3:
        if superanswer[3] == superguess [3]:
            right_spot += 1
            superanswer[3] = "x"
            superguess[3] = "y"
        elif superanswer[3] == superguess[1]:
            wrong_spot +=1
            superguess[1] ="w"
        elif superanswer[3] == superguess[2]:
            wrong_spot +=1
            superguess[2] ="w"
        elif superanswer[3] == superguess[0]:
            wrong_spot +=1
            superguess[0] ="w"
        if len(line) > 4:
            if superanswer[3] == superguess[4]:
                wrong_spot +=1
                superguess[4] ="w"
        if len(line) > 4:
            if superanswer[4] == superguess [4]:
                right_spot += 1
                superanswer[4] = "x"
                superguess[4] = "y"
            elif superanswer[4] == superguess[1]:
                wrong_spot +=1
                superguess[1] ="w"
            elif superanswer[4] == superguess[2]:
                wrong_spot +=1
                superguess[2] ="w"
            elif superanswer[4] == superguess[3]:
                wrong_spot +=1
                superguess[3] ="w"
            elif superanswer[4] == superguess[0]:
                wrong_spot +=1
                superguess[0] ="w"
    if superguess == line1:
        board[35] = right_spot
        board[36] = wrong_spot
    elif superguess == line2:
        board[37] = right_spot
        board[38] = wrong_spot
    elif superguess == line3:
        board[39] = right_spot
        board[40] = wrong_spot
    elif superguess == line4:
        board[41] = right_spot
        board[42] = wrong_spot
    elif superguess == line5:
        board[43] = right_spot
        board[44] = wrong_spot
brute_force_checking()
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with the whole board is, as you have discovered, repetitive and error prone. Your code is also trying to compute matches and display results at the same time. That makes a rather tricky algorithm unnecessarily harder.

Take a row-at-a-time approach. For this you need a function that compares a guess with the correct position and returns an evaluation of the guess. Once that is correct, how you display the returned evaluation is up to you.

This function accepts two *n*-digit numbers, `correct` and `guess` and returns two *n*-lists, `correct_positions` and `incorrect_positions`. The first shows the symbols that are in correct positions, or `None` if the symbol at that position in the guess was incorrect. The second shows symbols in the remaining positions if they were present in `correct` but at a different position, and `None` if they were completely wrong.

You can probably squeeze the three loops into list comprehensions if you have a taste for that sort of thing.

```
def evaluate_move(correct: int, guess: int) -> tuple[list]:
    correct = [int(x) for x in str(correct)]
    guess = [int(x) for x in str(guess)]
    assert len(correct) == len(guess)
    # establish the symbols in correct positions
    correct_positions = [c if c==g else None for c,g in zip(correct,guess)]
    # establish matching symbols in the wrong positions
    remainder_correct = []
    for i in range(len(correct)):
        if correct_positions[i] is not None:
            remainder_correct.append(None)
        else:
            remainder_correct.append(correct[i])
    remainder_guess = []
    for i in range(len(correct)):
        if correct_positions[i] is not None:
            remainder_guess.append(None)
        else:
            remainder_guess.append(guess[i])
    scratch = remainder_correct[:]
    # Need a scratch copy of the correct position to avoid double counting
    incorrect_positions = []
    for g in remainder_guess:
        if g and g in scratch:
            scratch.remove(g)
            incorrect_positions.append(g)
        else:
            incorrect_positions.append(None)
    return correct_positions, incorrect_positions


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for test in ((201234,202314),
                 (123456,111111),
                 (123456,654321),
                 ):
        print(evaluate_move(*test))
```

Output is

```
([2, 0, None, None, None, 4], [None, None, 2, 3, 1, None])
([1, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None])
([None, None, None, None, None, None], [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```